# Write code that assigns to double 'b' the result of rounding double 'a' to the nearest integer

Tags: java

I don't know what to do... I have two doubles and I need b to be the result of a rounded to the nearest integer...

```
// Enter a value to test here 
double a = ; 
double b; 

// Enter your code here
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have two doubles and I need `b` to be the result of `a` rounded to the nearest integer.

You could use [`Math.round(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29) which (per the Javadoc) returns *the value of the argument rounded to the nearest `long` value.*

```
double b = Math.round(a);
```

Comment: According to the javaDoc using the method on a long rounds to the nearest integer therefore I suggest you cast the value as so Math.round((long)a)  in order to get the desired result

Answer (score 0):

As Elliott mentioned you can use the `Math.round()` function but when you give it a parameter of type double it returns a value of type long but according to the javaDoc if you supply it with a parameter of type long, you will get an integer which is the desired result therefore you have 2 ways of doing so:

1. casting the double into a long and then as so:

   Math.round((long) a);
2. If you don't like the first way for some reason you can just wrap it with another round() function as so:

   /* as you can see the first one converts the double into a long and the second rounds the long into an int which gives the same result as the first option */
   Math.round(Math.round(a));